# uvm_sequence_item get_type_name should be virtual

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Looking at the uvm base classes, I noticed uvm_sequence_item method get_type_name is not defined as virtual. That means if I have a derived class that is downcasted to uvm_sequence_item handle, then get_type_name call on this handle will return wrong value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_type_name` is `virtual` in 1.2. Here is an excerpt of the source code of `uvm_object`:

```
virtual function string get_type_name (); return "<unknown>"; endfunction
```

`get_type_name` is not overridden in `uvm_sequence_item`. (So where are you getting your information?) Even if it were, you do not have to label a method as `virtual` if the base-class method is `virtual`.

Comment: I agree get_type_name is virtual in uvm_object, I was talking about uvm_sequence_item method that is not virtual.

I see that in UVM 1.1d 
```
      function string get_type_name();
        return "uvm_sequence_item";
     endfunction
```
So you're saying since the base class method is virtual, it doesn't matter if it's redefined not virtual in derived classes ?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying.